# Problem adding bibliography to LyX docs using OS X Sierra

Tags: bibtex, lyx, mac

I'm having some problems with LyX in OS Sierra. Specifically, I want to add a new bibliography, but LyX keeps on crashing. This is how it unfolds:

1. I click on menu tab Insert —> list/toc —> bibtex bibliography
2. The normal dialogue box comes up
3. I click on the “Add..” button under databases
4. A new dialogue box comes up, I click on the "Browse" button to find my `.bib` file
5. I find the `.bib` file I want it in Finder, I select it by double clicking on it
6. Then the entire program freezes

I know the `.bib` file hasn't been corrupted, because I can still generate bibliographies using LyX files where the same `.bib` file has already been added (that is, added to a document before I upgraded to Sierra), and I can drag and drop the "BibTeX Generated Bibliography" from an existing document to the new document, and it compiles fine.

The problem is everything worked fine until OS X Sierra, and using the old `.bib` file severely restricts where I store my `.bib` file and how I update it.

Has anyone else had this problem? Any advice?

Comment: Have you reported the problem to the Lyx developers? Do you have the latest version of Lyx?

Comment: Please make a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac and in the keywords put "os=macosx". Do you by chance have a program called "karabiner" running? (check this in the list of running programs)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - was not aware of how to report these. (also, no luck on karabiner, but thanks for the help all the same!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, on macOS Sierra 10.12.3, the issue was that after adding the database from the Finder file manager, the small "Add" window would move to background from the main "Insert Bibtex Bibliography" window. This makes it appear as if the program has freezed, while in fact the small window is in the background; it has to be manually moved into focus and closed before closing the main prompt. Hopefully, this proves to be the case for you.